# Need help, Caused By: org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

can somebody help me? I didn't open my test for 3 months, and now I tried to continue writing tests, but I get the error after starting and the browser just closing after the start. But 3 months ago this working without any issues.

TestNG version 7.4.0

Maven version Apache Maven 3.8.1

JDK version 1.8.0_192

**Here is the error log:**

```
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process

Cannot instantiate class com.test.test.test.ComparePricesTest
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:733)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:265)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1314)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1159)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:932)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

**Also here log from surefire:**

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class com.test.test.test.ComparePricesTest
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor(InstanceCreator.java:193)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstanceUsingObjectFactory(InstanceCreator.java:113)
    at org.testng.internal.InstanceCreator.createInstance(InstanceCreator.java:79)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:25)
    at org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense(GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:30)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:112)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:165)
    at org.testng.TestClass.getInstances(TestClass.java:122)
    at org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:102)
    at org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:94)
    at org.testng.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:59)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:463)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:339)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:292)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:183)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:173)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:107)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1300)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1276)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1125)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:428)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:562)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:548)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:23)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 89
Current browser version is 91.0.4472.114 with binary path /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Seregas-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:14b6:66e6:a891:514b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '1.8.0_291'
Driver info: driver.version: Driver
remote stacktrace: 0   chromedriver                        0x000000011011fb59 chromedriver + 2595673
1   chromedriver                        0x00000001107d3b33 chromedriver + 9624371
2   chromedriver                        0x000000010fecf773 chromedriver + 169843
3   chromedriver                        0x000000010fef3bf6 chromedriver + 318454
4   chromedriver                        0x000000010feefdc4 chromedriver + 302532
5   chromedriver                        0x000000010feed032 chromedriver + 290866
6   chromedriver                        0x000000010ff20234 chromedriver + 500276
7   chromedriver                        0x000000010ff1b4f3 chromedriver + 480499
8   chromedriver                        0x000000010fef5cd6 chromedriver + 326870
9   chromedriver                        0x000000010fef6ba7 chromedriver + 330663
10  chromedriver                        0x00000001100edb09 chromedriver + 2390793
11  chromedriver                        0x00000001100fabcc chromedriver + 2444236
12  chromedriver                        0x00000001100fa6ee chromedriver + 2442990
13  chromedriver                        0x00000001100d4832 chromedriver + 2287666
14  chromedriver                        0x00000001100fb63f chromedriver + 2446911
15  chromedriver                        0x00000001100e3299 chromedriver + 2347673
16  chromedriver                        0x00000001101128b9 chromedriver + 2541753
17  chromedriver                        0x0000000110125008 chromedriver + 2617352
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff707db2eb _pthread_body + 126
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff707de249 _pthread_start + 66
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff707da40d thread_start + 13

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:134)
    at com.test.webdriverfactory.Driver.getWebDriverInstance(Driver.java:19)
    at com.test.helpers.AppManager.<init>(AppManager.java:17)
    at com.test.helpers.SingletoneManager.<init>(SingletoneManager.java:10)
    at com.test.helpers.SingletoneManager.getInstance(SingletoneManager.java:15)
    at com.test.testConfig.TestBase.<init>(TestBase.java:15)
    at com.test.test.test.ComparePricesTest.<init>(ComparePricesTest.java:6)
```

**Here my POM file:**

```
 <groupId>TestP</groupId>
    <artifactId>testP</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.4</aspectj.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin-version>3.0.0-M5</maven-surefire-plugin-version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
        <local.repo>${settings.localRepository}</local.repo>
        <suiteFile>full</suiteFile>
        <allure.results>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</allure.results>
        <allure-testng-version></allure-testng-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-java-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:${local.repo}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${basedir}/src/test/resources/${suiteFile}.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportVersion>2.13.3</reportVersion>
                    <allureDownloadUrl>
                        https://dl.bintray.com/qameta/maven/io/qameta/allure/allure-commandline/2.13.3/allure-commandline-2.13.3.zip
                    </allureDownloadUrl>
                    <reportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/allure-reports</reportDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>full</id>
            <properties>
                <suiteFile>full</suiteFile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>smoke</id>
            <properties>
                <suiteFile>smoke</suiteFile>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>

**TestBase class:**
```

```
static WebDriver driver;

protected AppManager app = SingletoneManager.getInstance().app;


@BeforeClass(description = "Open homepage")
public void openBrowser()  {
  driver = app.getDriver();
  app.getNavigationHelper().navigateToHomePage();

}

@AfterSuite(description = "Close browser")
public void closeBrowser(){
    driver.quit();
}


public static WebDriver getDriver(){return driver;}
```

**AppManager class:**

```
AppManager(){
        driver = getWebDriverInstance();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

        attributeHelper = new AttributeHelper(driver, wait);
        navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(driver, wait);

    }

    public AttributeHelper getAttributeHelper() {
        return attributeHelper;
    }

    public NavigationHelper getNavigationHelper() {
        return navigationHelper;
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver(){
        return driver;
    }
}
```

**Singelton class**

```
public class SingletoneManager {

    private static SingletoneManager singletoneManager = null;

    public AppManager app;

    private SingletoneManager(){
      app = new AppManager();
    }

    public static synchronized SingletoneManager getInstance(){
        if(singletoneManager == null)
            singletoneManager = new SingletoneManager();
        return singletoneManager;
    }
}
```

**And ComparePrices class:**

```
public class ComparePricesTest extends TestBase {

    @Test(priority = 0, description = "click on Deal")
    public void getDeal() throws InterruptedException {
        app.getNavigationHelper().clickOnDealBtn();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void ComparePrice() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(8000);
        app.getAttributeHelper().getOfferPriceOnSearchResultPage();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should read the errors more carefully! "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 89 Current browser version is 91.0.4472.114" Indicates that your browser has updated, probably automatically, but you did not update your chromedriver.

Comment: yes, thank you, my mistake I check the version on my crhome browser and there I have Version 89.0.4389.114 (Official Build) (x86_64), I think this is the reason why I missed this, thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading maven-surefire-plugin to 2.19.1 should resolve the issue. You also get error for chrome drver 89 not supporting chrome 91. You may need to upgrade chrome driver 89 to 91.

Comment: Thanks, I really can't understand how I missed the error with chromedriver :)